# Import slow-mo video into app

Tags: ios, video, edit, slowmotion

Playing around slow-mo video lately. Looks like it's a video with adjustable "slow-mo period", and tightly integrated with iOS itself.

Say I write an app to mess around with the video, do you think it's possible to get iOS handles or APIs that allow you to know that video's setting?

Thanks!